# Zend Multiselect Empty Array When Submit

Tags: arrays, forms, zend-framework, select, multi-select

When I submit a form on my localhost everything is okay.

When I var_dump submitted data it gets me only

```
    Array ( [nameBg] => PVC
        [orderField] => 50 
        **[option] => Array** 
            [status] => 1 [id] => 10 
            [parentId] => 1 
            [page] => 1 
            [of] => orderField 
            [od] => DESC 
            [save] => Submit 
        )
```

and nothing more.. The option array is empty :( Could this be because of some server settings?

This is how my multi select element looks like.

```
    $this->addElement ( 'multiselect', 'option', array (
        'label' => $this->translate ( 'Опции' ),
        'decorators' => array (
                'ViewHelper' 
        ),
        'description' => $this->translate ( 'Add options' ),
        'multiOptions' => $catys,
        'validators' => array (
                array (
                        'GreaterThan',
                        true,
                        array (
                                0,
                                'messages' => array (
                                        Zend_Validate_GreaterThan::NOT_GREATER => $this->translate ( 'Please select an option.' ) 
                                ) 
                        ) 
                ) 
        ),
        'onclick' => ('selectMultiple(this);') 
) );
```

Comment: I find the dump of your _POST to be confusing.  Is the value of 'option' the text `array`?  As in your dump is not going that deep?  Are you using some weird settings with xdebug or something?  What did you intend those `**` to denote?  Now, why would it work one place and not the other? PHP settings, OS, etc?  What is different.

Comment: With ** i wanted to bold the text. The value of 'option' is array like

0 => 2

1 => 6

2 => 4

3 => 7

What PHP settings will influence on arrays? In my localhost I am running on Windows 7 and the server is on FreeBSD.

Comment: CaSe sensitivity would be the obvious difference between those platforms.  Anything specific to array functions would be more to do with PHP version.

Comment: Actually i found that the problem comes from 

`if ( in_array( strtolower( ini_get( 'magic_quotes_gpc' ) ), array( '1', 'on' ) ) ) {
            $_POST = array_map( 'stripslashes', $_POST );
            $_GET = array_map( 'stripslashes', $_GET );
            $_COOKIE = array_map( 'stripslashes', $_COOKIE );
        }`